# Why does this function call ruin the program and lead to undefined variables?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables, undefined

```
function getLatLng(address) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address' : address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert("Aus getLatLng: adresse:"+address+"Ergebnis: "+results[0].geometry.location);
            return results[0].geometry.location;
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: "
                    + status);
        }
    });
}
```

I am using this javascript function in another function to get the Latitude/Longitude values from a string which is the address. The alert shows that the conversion is successfull but if i call the method i get a javascript error that it's still undefined.

```
    var start = document.getElementById("route_start").value;
    start = getLatLng(start);
    alert("Start: "+start);
```

What am i missing? The alert always shows an undefined variable. Why is that? 
I tried everything. Everything is going well til i call the function getLatLng. Something with the return isn't working. :(

Comment: `getLatLng` doesn't return anything...

Comment: as noted above - it doesn't return anything -- it is asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getLatLng` function doesn't actually return anything, which is why `start` is undefined.

The return statement that you have written is contained within the anonymous function that gets passed to `geocoder.geocode`, so this won't actually get returned from your outer function.

Since `geocoder.geocode` is asynchronous you won't be able to write a `getLatLng` which returns the result in this way, instead you need to pass a callback function as an argument and invoke this function when the geocode API returns a value, something like:

```
function getLatLng(address, callback) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address' : address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            callback(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: "
                    + status);
        }
    });
}
```